# WPF Binding.Stringformat ignored

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

With .NET 3.5 SP 1 I checked out [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) and followed instructions, however the `StringFormat` parameter still gets ignored.
Any possible reasons?
**To be sure: the datatype that are involved are DateTime, double, int. So the formatting SHOULD work, but it's not.**
Any clues why?

EDIT: here's the code!

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=TotalHours, StringFormat=Total hours: {}{0:00}}"/>
```

Comment: Please post your non-working code.

Comment: See above! This is one of many variations I tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=TotalHours, StringFormat='Total hours: {0:00}'}"/>
```

`{}` is necessary only if the format string starts with a `{`, to escape it, otherwise it'll be recognized as a markup extension. I also like to enclose the `StringFormat` with simple quotes to avoid problems.